# Send message without request

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-actix

How do you send a websocket server response (like a json blob) without receiving a message from the client.

For example, how would you make an actix webserver that sends a message to a connected client whenever it receives a message from an mpsc?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to use the `actix-ws` (sub-)library. I found it too hard to do directly using the `actix` actors. This nice [example](https://crates.io/crates/actix-ws) gives a `session` object. You can call `session.send(...)` whenever you want, not just in the incoming message handler.